# Python: Acessar 4º nível de uma pasta zipada

Tags: python

Olá!

Gostaria de acessar o 4º nível de uma pasta zipada. Ou seja, tenho um arquivo zip e dentro dele há uma pasta e dentro desta tem outra pasta e assim por diante... conforme gráfico abaixo.

Eu gostaria de pegar um arquivo cuja extensão é ".csv".

Como posso fazer isso diretamente?

Eu já consigo descomprimir, porém eu teria que fazer outro código para navegar dentro desses pastas. Isso eu sei fazer. Eu só gostaria de fazer o trabalho de uma vez só, com um único código. Podem me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ja desenvolveu algo?

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar: https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/compressing-and-extracting-files-in-python--cms-26816

Comment: Após extraído, não bastaria ler o arquivo `pasta1/pasta2/pasta3/pasta4/arquivo.csv`? Não entendi qual é a dúvida de fato.

Comment: Agradeço comentarem. Em resposta: A dúvida é extrair apenas aquele arquivo. O que farei depois não faz parte da pergunta.

Comment: Maury Developer, eu já conheço o site indicado. Ele não ajuda. A orientação que tem ali é sobre extrair arquivos... Eu quero extrair arquivo que está dentro do 4º nível da pasta comprimida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde, Wilson !
Então cara, sua pergunta tem alguns buracos quanto ao por que de fazer o que se pede sendo que existem meios de se desenvolver que não são necessários a automação na hora de colher arquivos dentro de diretorios, mas mesmo assim aqui está algo parecido com o que pediste, fiz em alguns minutos, usei a imagem que anexou a pergunta como exemplo, ou seja, criei um arquivo.zip -> pasta1 -> pasta2 -> pasta3 -> pasta4 -> Arquivo.csv.

O script extrai o arquivo.zip e coleta automaticamente os nomes dos diretórios e vai buscando dentro de cada diretorio a existência do arquivo "Arquivo.csv", se nao acha ele, procura dentro de outro diretorio e assim sucessivamente, aqui está o código:

```
import zipfile
import os
from os import listdir
import glob

with zipfile.ZipFile(os.getcwd() +'/'+ listdir(os.getcwd())[1],'r') as zip:
    zip.extractall()

n = 0
cond = ''
filename = []
filename = listdir(os.getcwd())[0]

while cond != 'Arquivo.csv':

    try:
        filename = filename+'/'+listdir(filename)[0]
    except:
        pass
        cond = filename.split('/')[n]
        n += 1 



print(filename)
```

A saída "Filename" será o diretório inteiro em que se localiza o "Arquivo.csv" e é ele que vc vai utilizar para manipular tal arquivo, se quiser alterar para que o código procure por uma extensão ".csv" apenas, sem nome específico é só alterar no while.

Conforme ele vai identificando diretorios ele vai salvando numa lista de nome "cond" e analisando o último item dessa lista, sempre pra achar o "arquivo.csv". Espero ter ajudado !

Comment: agradeço sua atenção meu amigo. A questão é essa mesma, extrair apenas o "arquivo.csv".           Vou estudar seu código para resolver um erro que está dando comigo e verificar o resultado final. Agradeço muito sua contribuição. Aliás, a duvida escrita desta forma é para facilitar, se eu for escrever muito o pessoal não compreenderá. Estou tentando trabalhar com aproximadamente 30 arquivos destes e para isso, preciso automatizar.

Comment: Entendi meu mano, boa sorte ai !